# Is there any way to find the execution flow of java code?

Tags: java

```
  public class Threads1 {
    int x = 0;
    public class Runner implements Runnable {
        public void run(){
            int current = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
                current = x;
                System.out.println(current + ", ");
                x = current + 2;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Threads1().go();
    }

    public void go(){
        Runnable r1 = new Runner();
        new Thread(r1).start();
        new Thread(r1).start();
    }
}
```

I want to find the execution step of this code ,Is there any way that can show me the execution flow in my consol?

Comment: What do you mean, "the execution flow"?

Comment: I want to find the step by step execution flow that The JVM gonna follow to execute this code.

Comment: run it in eclipse with a debugger

Comment: I am using NetBeans dose It provide any support for this?

Comment: @TanvirArafat That's something you should just train yourself to do. Knowing how to look at code and see where execution will go based on the the state of the variables is a crucial skill. A tool to help may make practicing a little easier, but this is certainly not something you should entirely offload to a tool.

Comment: You can also just sprinkle print statements all over and watch them print. That would be the simplest way.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thanks for your advice :) .

Comment: You have threads. There will be one "flow" per thread, and all the flows will execute simultaneously.  However, your threads are so short-lived that one may complete before the other even starts, depending on how the JVM and OS schedule things.

Comment: "I am using NetBeans dose It provide any support for this?" -  try Googling "netbeans debugger"

Answer (score 1):

#### Print Statements

Put `System.out.println()` statements in appropriate places in your code. For example, put

```
System.out.println("Entering a for loop");
```

before a for loop to know when the for loop is entered.

#### Debugger

Find out how to set a breakpoint in your IDE. Set a breakpoint at start of the portion of code that you don't understand. When that line is going to be executed, the program will pause and allow you to examine the values in variables, the stack trace, the threads, etc. You can also find out which thread is the current line running on in the debugger.

Additionally, find "Step in", "Step over" and "Step out" buttons on the debugger. These will allow you to "step through" your code line by line, so as to allow you to see the path that execution takes.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possibilities is to create a field in the class that would differentiate both threads to make you sure which thread prints the values to the console in the moment (you should contain this additional value in the informations you print to the console in the "for" loop to know if the first or the second thread has performed activity printed to the console).

Another possibility is using debugger.

Answer (score 0):

**Java Threads**
If you have several threads running at once ther is no way to predict which one of them finishes first or when something is done, like to differen programms. Different threads are executed by different cores of you CPU and therefore completely independend from oneanother, this affects computation speed and order (branchprediction in you CPU plays one role here). This can lead to pretty difficult bugs to find because they only happen sometimes.

**Your Problem**
The execution order of the threads is not determend a compile time it's decided by you CPU at runtime and is **not consistent** because the threads do not know they have a partner.

**Solution**
To display the order at which it happend just insert `System.out.println` statements in your methodes and create so a sort of log what happened in you console.

**Controled Threads with Synchronized**
If you use threads, Java supports the `synchronized` keyword. Synchronized allows you to get a bit of control over several threads. For example only one thread at a time can interact with a variable or methode. For more information just google Java synchronized threads.